# Inductor using thick film technology

Tags: inductor

Can we make inductor in thick film technology to use as in hybrid micro circuits?

If so what is the wattage limitation?

Comment: See questions and comments below. Please add extra material to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - an inductor can be made using anything that has magnetic coupling between various portions of itself. Use of PCB tracks as inductors is well known and thick film methods are essentially just an extension of that.

What do you want to do with it?
The limitations of non-metallic inductors are more liable to be Q than power rating - this will depend greatly on required inductance and current capability, so application will play a significant part.

Power handling is liable to be influenced by temperature rise which is (of course) affected by current if power handling is envisaged. To get some idea of power limits you'd need to better specify your conditions. An imcomplete list would include:

- what frequency,
- what current,
- what application,
- what inductance,
- what area is available
- what voltage isolation is required (if any)
- Do you intend to fabricate multiple layers and if so how?

  - or one layer only,
  - or one on each side of a single PCB,
  - or a pcb sandwich,
  - or ... ?

---

[Murata chip inductors](http://www.murata.com/new/news_release/2009/0528/)

[KOA **thin** film chip inductors](http://www.koaproducts.com/kl73_en.php)

Comment: I want to make an LED driver using thick film technology,i mean micro circuit, where resistor and capacitors are printed on the ceramic substrate which is having 99.8% alumina,then this micro circuit will be placed on the single  sided PCB,so on the PCB inductor will come, but instead of placing like this if inductor can be made using thick film technology then i can include inductor also on the micro circuit itself.

Comment: Even carbon is having magnetic properties so if i print carbon or copper in coil format dus it becums an inductor?? i dunno exactly how i have to design the inductor using material having magnetic properties??

Comment: Additional relevant information should be placed in the question. You will get far far far better responses from people if you use "normal" English 0 capitalise "i", spell ~= correctly, avoid 'sland" (eg dunno) , use full words and not text speak.  || An inducytor can be made of any conductive matertial. eg Copper wire is not ferro-magnetic. You should provide much much more information about what you want to achieve (and not a lot about "how" unless it is an essential part of the solution. If this is an assignment you should say so.  | What is is for overall?